# Tengo modelo, vista y controlador, ¿por qué me sigue saltando un 404?

Tags: php, yii2

Estoy montando un sistema de subida de archivos en una aplicación hecha en yii2.

**Tengo montado el modelo:**

```
<?php
namespace frontend\models;

use yii\base\Model;



/**
 * Signup form
 */
class UploadEmployeeDocumentForm extends Model


{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $pdfFile;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['pdfFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'pdf'],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->pdfFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->pdfFile->baseName . '.' . $this->pdfFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Tengo la vista:**

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'pdfFile')->fileInput() ?>

    <button>Enviar</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

**Y tengo el controlador:**

```
<?php


namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use frontend\models\UploadEmployeeDocumentForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadEmployeeDocumentController extends Controller
{
public function actionUpload()
{
$model = new UploadEmployeeDocumentForm();

if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
$model->pdfFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'pdfFile');
if ($model->UploadEmployeeDocumentForm()) {
// el archivo se subió con exito
return;
}
}

return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
}
}
```

Pues con todo esto, cuando llamo a la vista desde la aplicación (usando `href="<?= Url::to(["employee/document/upload"]) ?>"`), me sigue devolviendo un 404 como si no existiese la página.

Por si sirve de algo os posteo por aquí el código del index de la vista:

```
<?php

use common\components\widgets\GridViewWidget;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;

$this->params['title'] = Yii::t('app', 'Documentos');

$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = [
    'label' => $this->params['title'],
];

?>
<div class="page-menu">
        <div class="btn-group dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-icon" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-expanded="false"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Acciones') ?><i class="dropdown-caret" style="margin-left: 5px"></i></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <?php if (Yii::$app->user->can('createEmployeeDocument')) { ?>
                <li><a href="<?= Url::to(["employee/document/upload"]) ?>"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Subir documento') ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="form-group field-document" style="margin-bottom: 20px;margin-top:20px;">
                <li><a style="width:150px;padding-left:15px;" href="<?= Url::to(["employee/document/upload"]) ?>"><?= Yii::t('app', ' Subir documentos') ?></a></li>
                <div class="col-md-6">
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

<?= GridViewWidget::widget([
    'id' => 'user-table',
    'dataProvider' => $employeeDocumentDataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $employeeDocumentSearchModel,
    'pjax' => true,
    'bordered' => false,
    'striped' => false,
    'condensed' => false,
    'responsive' => true,
    'hover' => true,
    'checks' => true,
    'contextMenu' => false,
    'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'clickable'],
    'clickAction' => 'redirectUser($(this))',
    'refreshButton' => true,
    'headerRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'filterRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'rowOptions' => function ($employeeDocumentModel) {
        if ($employeeDocumentModel) {
            return [
                'class' => is_null($employeeDocumentModel->enabled) ? 'warning' : (!$employeeDocumentModel->enabled ? 'danger' : ''),
                'data-enabled' => is_null($employeeDocumentModel->enabled) ? 0 : (!$employeeDocumentModel->enabled ? 0 : 1),
            ];
        }
    },
    'columns' => [
        [
            'vAlign' => 'middle',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'width' => '32px',
            'value' => function ($employeeDocumentModel) {
                return Html::img($employeeDocumentModel->employeeDocumentUrl ?: Url::to(['/img/default-document.png']), ['class' => 'img-circle img-document media-object', 'style' => 'margin-top: 32px;']);
            },
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'user_id',
            'vAlign' => 'middle',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'vAlign' => 'middle',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'employee_document_date',
            'vAlign' => 'middle',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'type',
            'vAlign' => 'middle',
        ],

    ],


]);

?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuándo te da 404? ¿Al cargar el formulario o al enviar el archivo?

Comment: Cuando cargo el formulario, directamente salta el 404 y no se por que no funciona.

Comment: ¿Te funcionan el resto de páginas? ¿Cómo has definido la ruta al formulario? (los `Url::to()`).

Comment: el resto de paginas van sin problemas, la ruta la he definido así: href="<?= Url::to(["employee/document/upload"])

Comment: ¿Podrías comprobar qué se ha generado en el `href` mirando el código html? ¿Qué reglas tienes definidas para esta ruta?

Comment: Ahh, ya veo, no me di cuenta.. redactando respuesta :D

Comment: Ya he redactado la respuesta, espero que sea la solución al problema que describes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo está relacionado con la nomenclatura de los controladores.

Para acceder al formulario has usado:

```
<a href="<?= Url::to(["employee/document/upload"]) ?>">...</a>
```

Según la [documentación acerca de la nomenclatura de controladores](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/es/structure-controllers#controller-class-naming):

> Los nombres de clases de controladores pueden ser derivados de los IDs de acuerdo a las siguientes reglas:
>
> - Transforma la primera letra de cada palabra separada por guiones en mayúscula. Nota que si el `ID` del controlador contiene barras, esta regla sólo aplica a la porción después de la última barra dentro del `ID`.
> - Elimina guiones y reemplaza cualquier barra diagonal por barras invertidas.
> - Agrega el sufijo `Controller`.
> - Agrega al principio el *controller namespace*.
>
> A continuación mostramos algunos ejemplos, asumiendo que el *controller namespace* toma el valor por defecto: `app\controllers`:
>
> - `article` deriva en `app\controllers\ArticleController`;
> - `post-comment` deriva en `app\controllers\PostCommentController`;
> - `admin/post-comment` deriva en `app\controllers\admin\PostCommentController`.

El enlace generado, según esas reglas, sería `app\controllers\employee\document\UploadController`.

Por lo que, teniendo en cuenta que has usado el nombre `UploadEmployeeDocumentController` bajo el espacio de nombres `app\controllers`, deberías haber usado:

```
<a href="<?= Url::to(["upload-employee-document"]) ?>">...</a>
```

Según las reglas anteriormente enumeradas, el resultado será `app\controllers\UploadEmployeeDocumentController`.

---

PD: Esta respuesta no solucionó completamente el problema. Amplío los datos que compartimos a través del chat para dar con la solución.

> Raúl Pineda: el archivo php está metido en: `frontend/views/employee-document/upload.php`

Según la [documentación acerca de las nomenclatura de vistas en yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/es/structure-views#organizing-views):

> Así como en controladores y modelos, existen convenciones para organizar las vistas.
>
> - Para vistas renderizadas por controladores, deberían colocarse en un directorio tipo `@app/views/ControllerID` por defecto, donde `ControllerID` se refiere al `ID` del controlador. Por ejemplo, si la clase del controlador es `PostController`, el directorio sería `@app/views/post`; Si fuera `PostCommentController`, el directorio sería `@app/views/post-comment`. En caso de que el controlador pertenezca a un módulo, el directorio sería `views/ControllerID` bajo el directorio del módulo.
> - Para vistas renderizadas por un widget, deberían ser puestas en un directorio tipo `WidgetPath/views` por defecto, donde `WidgetPath` se refiere al directorio que contiene a la clase del widget.
> - Para vistas renderizadas por otros objetos, se recomienda seguir una convención similar a la utilizada con los widgets.

Según estos puntos, si el controlador se llama `UploadEmployeeDocumentController` y se llama a la vista con `$this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);`, entonces la ruta correcta a ella debería ser `frontend/views/upload-employee-document/upload.php`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, aun así, esto sigue sin funcionar, he mirado en los params, he mirado los permisos y he mirado a ver si se me había colado alguna variable y no deja de saltar el 404, estoy seguro que sera una tontería, pero no doy con la tecla en encontrarla.

Comment: ¿Podrías actualizar la página donde tienes el enlace `href` (en vez de pulsar el botón "atrás") y volver a intentarlo? También, si es posible, dime qué se ha generado en el `href` mirando el código HTML. ¿En qué ruta has metido el archivo PHP y con qué nombre?

Comment: el archivo php esta metido en:  frontend/views/employee-document/upload.php y el href ha generado: <link href="/assets/551d72f6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/nifty.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/nifty-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/themes/type-d/theme-ocean.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/e8b27278/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/assets/dc81fb2d/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/db19f684/yii.js"></script>
<script src="/js/site.js"></script>

Comment: Me refiero al controlador, aunque me voy oliendo dónde estará. Además, me refiero al `href` generado con `href="<?= Url::to(["upload-employee-document"]) ?>"` que me dijiste. Es importante que me respondas dónde está el controlador porque tiene pinta que no has proporcionado el correcto adecuado a la ruta usada y por eso no funciona.

Comment: Perdona, estoy empezando y aun soy tela de torpe, pero no te entiendo que quieres decir con de lo que esta generando el href.

Comment: Olvida por ahora esa parte, es más importante saber dónde tienes el controlador y su nombre de archivo.

Comment: el controlador lo engo aquí: frontend/controllers/UploadEmployeeDocumentController.php

Comment: Para no extender la conversación en los comentarios, [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82660/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-raul-pineda).